# Quckblox q-municate Video chat 'Token Required'

Tags: android, api, quickblox

Playing with Quickblox's q-municate for android and had success with video chat for a day.

I am now getting an error simply saying "Token Required." I know the session has timed out after two hours based on Quickblox documentation.

Would there be a tutorial on how to correct this problem?

I've read this [documentation](http://quickblox.com/developers/Authentication_and_Authorization) but am still lost on how to piece this all together.

I've found this code in QBAuthHelp.java file, is this the method to authenticate video chat?

```
public QBUser login(QBUser inputUser) throws QBResponseException, BaseServiceException {
    QBUser user;
    QBAuth.createSession();
    String password = inputUser.getPassword();
    user = QBUsers.signIn(inputUser);
    String token = QBAuth.getBaseService().getToken();
    user.setPassword(password);
    AppSession.startSession(LoginType.EMAIL, user, token);
    return user;
```

Thank you for any help here, I'm a complete newbie here.

Answer (score 3):

you need to get session in your app with the QBAuth method..
Authentication require, so you can get Token and create session successfully.

Comment: I believe I've found the session QBAuth method, it is listed in the above question. I do appreciate any help on what I might be doing wrong here.

Answer (score 2):

when start your application to first autheticate your app with your quickblox account after you signup. 
1.create Application class in your app.

```
public class VideoChatApplication extends Application {

   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
   super.onCreate();

          QBSettings.getInstance().fastConfigInit(Constant.APP_ID,
        Constant.AUTH_KEY, Constant.AUTH_SECRET);
  }

}
```

2 define your application class in your manifest file

```
<application
android:name=".VideoChatApplication"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

<activity
    android:name=".Signup"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity></application>
```

3 first you need to sign up the user after login to user

```
    private void createSession(final String login, final String password) {
    final QBUser user = new QBUser(login, password);
    QBAuth.createSession(login, password,
            new QBEntityCallbackImpl<QBSession>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(QBSession session, Bundle bundle) {
                    user.setId(session.getUserId());

                    QBChatService.getInstance().login(user,
                            new QBEntityCallbackImpl<QBUser>() {

                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(QBUser result,
                                        Bundle params) {

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess() {
                                    // login success

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onError(List errors) {
                                    Toast.makeText(this,
                                            "Error when login",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    for (Object error : errors) {
                                    }
                                }
                            });

                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    super.onSuccess();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(List<String> errors) {
                    Toast.makeText(this,
                            "Error when login, check test users login and password",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you modify Q-municate code?

"Token Required" means that you are trying to do a request(any) to QuickBlox backend, but you did not create a session before.

The 1st request in all QuickBlox apps should be a session creation request:

```
QBAuth.createSession(...
```

then wait till this request will be finished and perform any other requests